# How does IfHasRights work(is it based on site or list)?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, security-trimming

So my sceario is this.
I have a subsite and in this subsite i have a custom webpart  that displays that from a blog under this subsite via web services.
The user doesn't has no permission to the blog and the posts list but when i open up the subsite i can see data on the custom webpart.

But when i click the link to view more data then i get access denied error.

But the problem is i don't want the user to see any data at all since he doesn't have access.

I have tried using all the IfHasRights - (ViewListItems - 1 )
Tried this

```
<xsl:if test="ddwrt:IfHasRights(1)">
<xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.rowview" />
</xsl:if>
```

But doesn't work
Thanks

Any ideas?
Thannks

Comment: Hmm... You wrote that you're using a custom webpart. But then, where do you put the XSLT? Are you actually using DataViewWebPart?

Comment: Yeah Andrey i'm using Dataview webpart via sharepoint designer

Answer (score 4):

IfHasRights checks the permissions based on the following permission set:

```
private SPBasePermissions CurrentPermissions()
{
    if (base.wp is DataFormWebPart)
    {
        DataFormWebPart wp = base.wp as DataFormWebPart;
        if (wp.ListItem != null)
        {
            return wp.ListItem.EffectiveBasePermissions;
        }
        if (wp.SPList != null)
        {
            return wp.SPList.EffectiveBasePermissions;
        }
        if (base.wp.Web != null)
        {
            return base.wp.Web.EffectiveBasePermissions;
        }
    }
    return SPBasePermissions.EmptyMask;
}
```

Which means that if the Webpart isn't inheriting from DataFormWebPart it'll return false. If it is then it'll be based on the general level of the DataFormWebPart

Comment: ThanksSorry Per i'm using DWP.

Comment: +1 for your exploration, Per!

Comment: @naijacoder: 1. DataViewWebPart inherits from DataFormWebPart. so Per's answer holds true. 2. Since obviously you're using SoapDataSource in conjunction with DVWP, IfHasRights will contain current user's permissions for the current **web**. Thus, IfHasRights will not do here for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks guys and that why my intention was to use IfHasRights but which number permisionMask will work for me in my scenario.
See my original post.
Cheers